# ExecuteNonQueryAsync hangs in MVC app

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a DAL project I call from my MVC controller. I pass the method a list of objects I want updated. I added break points and it gets to ExecuteNonQueryAsync() and then just hangs. The website keeps "loading" and it never gets to return 1; The query worked before I tried to move it to execute async (you can see where I commented out the execution of the query. I did delete the connection open/close pieces but the query worked fine before this.

Also I updated the code below so I can post it with OBJECT, ListObjects and COL1/COL2 instead of the actual values/object names used.

Thanks in advance!

```
static async Task<int> NonQuery(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        return 1;
    }

public static bool updateQuery(List<OBJECT> listObjects)
    {
        string cnn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ToString();
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(cnn))
        {
            StringBuilder SQLQuery = new StringBuilder();

            SQLQuery.AppendLine("UPDATE TABLENAME ");
            SQLQuery.AppendLine("SET COL1 = @COL1, ");
            SQLQuery.AppendLine("WHERE COL2 = @COL2 ");

            //mySqlConnection.Open();

            foreach (ObjectType ot in listObjects)
            {
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLQuery.ToString(), mySqlConnection);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@COL1", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = COL1VALUE;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@COL2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = COL2VALUE;

                int result = NonQuery(mySqlConnection, cmd).Result;

                //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            //mySqlConnection.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[As I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), this is a common problem when converting your code to `async`. The proper solution is to replace all `Result` and `Wait` calls with `await`, as such:

```
public static async Task<bool> updateQueryAsync(List<OBJECT> listObjects)
{
  ...
  int result = await NonQueryAsync(mySqlConnection, cmd);
  ...
}

static async Task<int> NonQueryAsync(SqlConnection conn, SqlCommand cmd)
```

I also changed your `async` methods to end in `Async`, as [specified by the TAP documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).